# Moving Tiny MCE before the textarea

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I want to customize tiny mce according to my needs. If someone have any idea about it please help me.

The issue is when you add tiny mce to your page it is positioned after your textarea in HTML dom. ie.

```
<textarea class="fckEditor required" name="data[Banneramend][summary]" id="data[Banneramend][summary]" style="display: none;"/>
<span id="data[Banneramend][summary]_parent" class="mceEditor defaultSkin"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="data[Banneramend][summary]_tbl" class="mceLayout" style="width: 450px; height: 170px;">.........
```

What i want is that when tiny mce is created it should look like.

```
<span id="data[Banneramend][summary]_parent" class="mceEditor defaultSkin"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="data[Banneramend][summary]_tbl" class="mceLayout" style="width: 450px; height: 170px;">.........<textarea class="fckEditor required" name="data[Banneramend][summary]" id="data[Banneramend][summary]" style="display: none;"/>
```

is there any function to do this, or do a clear hack will be the best idea.

Gaurav

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `theme_advanced_toolbar_location` in the TinyMCE's `init` function

```
tinyMCE.init({
...
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top"
});
```

[wiki reference](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/theme_advanced_toolbar_location)